# How to navigate to home from splash screen in second time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 Timer(
    Duration(seconds: 5),
    () => Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())));
}
```

I have timer of 5 seconds to navigate to the Home() page. When i run the app for the very first time it navigate to the home screen but when i back to splash screen again. it loads for a life time.

How can i navigate every time to home screen after 5 seconds?

Comment: why do you even need to go back to the splash screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to go back to the splash screen from `Home()` page.

Then you may use `Navigator.pushReplacement()`instead.

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 Timer(
    Duration(seconds: 5),
    () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())));
}
```